# How can I change the spawn location?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I'm playing GTA Online on PC.

The first garage I bought was somewhere up north, far away from the actual city. Now after making some money I got myself an apartment (w/ garage) in the city.

The problem is, that when I join a session (doesn't matter if solo/friend/public) I always spawn in the garage I bought first (the one far away from the city), but I'd rather like to spawn in my apartments garage or the apartment itself. How do I change this? I searched for an option but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press the `M` button on PC, or hold `Select` on console. In this list there should be an option that allows you to cycle trough all possible spawns available to you. Just select the one you want, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, this does not work in GTA V